# AspNetCore - Injecting a Func<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core controller I am creating. The controller endpoint looks something like this right now:

```cs
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Thing>> AddThing([FromBody] string otherThingId)
  {
    // First I perform some validation here (null check, proper ID, etc).

    // Next I get OtherThing to make a Thing out of it
    // _getOtherThing is at the heart of what I'm trying to understand
    var sample = await _getOtherThing(otherThingId);

    // Finally I do some work to convert it to a Thing and send it back
    return newThing;
  }
```

`_getOtherThing` is a method that performs a very specific concrete call to another API to get the data I needed. It's a method that takes a string and returns a `Task<OtherThing>`. There are issues with this method as it is though, such as testing, sharing it in the code base, and swapping implementations later on.

To me, it seems like it's an external dependency. So it would make sense to pass it into the controller. The controller class does with the Repository it uses via DI like so:

```cs
public ThingController(IThingRepository thingRepo)
{
  _thingRepo = thingRepo;
}
```

The interface and its concrete implementation are then supplied for injection in the `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IThingRepository, ThingRepository>();
}
```

So I end up with two questions:

1. What is the most common/expected way to extract this function and then supply it to the controller?
2. If I did want to just supply a function, what is the most reasonable way to do it?

With respect to the first question - Here are two strategies I could think of. Are there others?

1. **Supply the function directly to the class.** What I came up with looks like this:

```cs
public ThingController(IThingRepository thingRepo, Func<string, Task<OtherThing>> getOtherThing)
{
  _thingRepo = thingRepo;
  _getOtherThing = getOtherThing;
}
```

And then during `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IThingRepository, ThingRepository>();
  services.AddSingleton<Func<string, Task<OtherThing>>>(
    OtherThingUtils.GetOtherThing
  );
}
```

2. **Convert the function into an interface/class pair and inject that**:

```cs
interface IOtherThingProvider {
  Task<OtherThing> getOtherThing(string id);
}
class OtherThingProvider : IOtherThingProvider {
  public async Task<OtherThing> getOtherThing(string id) 
  {
    // original code here
  }
}
```

And then in the `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IThingRepository, ThingRepository>();
  services.AddSingleton<IOtherThingProvider, OtherThingProvider>();
}
```

Comment: Also if this is the wrong context to post this in, or if the post is missing something for Cod Review, let me know and I'll correct.

Comment: (This looks *solution looking for a problem* - can you sketch a use case?)

Comment: Thanks. My main question was around typical practices in C#. Is it unusual to pass a function directly to a class like this? I will try and clarify!

Comment: I took some time to edit the question to hopefully be more fitting. I left the solutions   could think of because they are at least one aspect of my question. Hopefully this helps. Thanks again for the feedback @greybeard

Comment: Also I see I misunderstood what the point of this StackExchange is. Is there a better one to post my question? It might fit fine on StackOverflow now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically butcher the entire reason to dependency inject here.
Some IoCs let you deffer injection by doing `public MyConstructor(Func<IMyInterface> factory)`. This is fine, because IMyInterface is an interface and the concrete implementation will be invoked through the standard pipeline and it can have its own dependencies.

But your solution cuts off the DI pipeline half way through and the `OverThingUtils.GetOtherThing` can not benefit from DI at all. And the special `Func<string, IType>` construct is dangerously close to service locator pattern.

I would create an interface,

```
interface IOtherThingProvider 
{
   Task<OtherThing> GetOtherThing(string id);
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is instead of using a function and defining the type in the constructor, I should build an interface/class and use that in the constructor? At that point the DI framework will do the work of creating an instance of the class when needed. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly,and the concrete type can benefit from DI and have its own dependencies. Etc, etc

Comment: Cool, thanks for answering! I also rewrote the question to hopefully be better than it was originally.

Comment: Just be careful with singleton scope. Anything injected into its constructor will be singleton.

Comment: You can Create a scope but for that you need to i have dependency to IServiceCollection and then you are again danger close to service locator pattern. Its fine for a few framework specific things. But you should be careful spreading depedency to the iOC. If need alot of scoped life times deep down in your domain. Its better to abstract the scope. I did this for one of my projects.  https://andersmalmgren.com/2015/06/23/abstract-di-container-scopes/